# How to set value of empty columns base on some conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas. I have the following problem:

[image]

I want to set columns B as a column A value for which C has NA value, until the next NA value in C column has appeared.
Here is a expected output:

[image]

Comment: `df['B'] = df.assign(B=np.where(df['C'].isna(), df['A'], np.nan))['B'].ffill()`?

Comment: Thanks, it works